# Concurrent usage of same data with Entity Framework (receive updates on other clients)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have an application that uses Entity Framework for its data, but now I've hit a wall I haven't figured out a way over.

So the basic use-case is that I have a set of data that is modified quite frequently and shown to every user connected at the time. Changes made on the client are not instantly saved to the database but only once the user commits the changes. Now, is it possible to build a system that informs the other users of the modifications made to the database and have them automatically refresh their context? I really wouldn't want to create a polling system of any kind, but instead receive events or something of the sort. Also the absolute best thing would be to allow for combining of the changes (say I'm editing itemA, another user edits itemB and commits the changes, I get an event and only update itemB still keeping the changes I've made thus far to itemA).

Possible version for use are EF 4.3.1 ObjectContext-based, or EF 5.0.0 DbContext-based versions. Used database is MS SQL.

Comment: Is it a web-application? If so, you could use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to signal clients from the server. If it's a desktop app, then *probably* you'd have to somehow keep track of clients currently using the applications and send them a notification via UDP (or TCP if you want the confirmation that recipient got the information). Still, it would just mean that the client receives the message and queries the database to get fresh data...

Comment: It's a desktop app. And yeah I'm kind of hoping I could somehow utilize sql server's triggers (which I've never used) or something of the sort.

Comment: It's actually quite interesting, 'cause I might have to do something similar in the near future, so I searched a little bit and found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server). It seems to be using [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class, so it might be worth taking a look.

Comment: That indeed seems interesting. Thanks for sharing!